# Can't get the most basic mobx store to work with observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I just started out trying mobx-react using stores, and want to use a store plus a single observable, but can't even get this to work.

With `@observer`, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'render' of object '#<ProxyComponent>'`.

Without it, the value becomes 1.

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, any ideas?

```
import {observable} from 'mobx'
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react'

class AppStore {
  @observable value = 1;
}

@inject('store') @observer
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {store} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {store.value}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const render = (Component) => {
  const appStore = new AppStore()
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={appStore}>
        <Component/>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  )
}

render(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a configuration (webpack hot loader) issue, and not an issue of the code itself (which runs under a jsfiddle).

Adding `'react-hot-loader/babel'` to `'plugins'` in webpack's `'babel-loader'` appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bit unclear, like from where are you importing `Provider` and `ReactDOM`.And also since `render` is a function used by `ReactDOM` so the `render()` function you have defined might conflict with the built in `render()` function.

And also [here it is explained](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/300)

> In general there are three ways in which you can pass stores in MobX
>
> 1) Explicitly via props. Easy to test and clear to follow, but can become
>   clumpsy when you have deeply nested structures or many stores (you can
>   solve the latter by having a store for stores)
>
> 2) Import stores in the
>   components directly and just use them :) It's the MVP of passing
>   stores around, but stand alone testing of components becomes tricky
>   quickly as you have to make sure your global stores are in the right
>   state first
>
> 3) Pass stores around via React's context mechanism. Redux's
>   Provider uses that, as does the mobx-connect package. Context is
>   passed implicitly and deep component can extract data out of the
>   context, but it is still easy to test as you only have to make sure
>   you set up some context before testing the component.

In your case you are using the 3rd point.So I have created a [jsfiddle here,](https://jsfiddle.net/npm5a02j/1/)
where the store is passed as props as in point 1.

Comment: Thanks but as you noted, I'm after an answer to mechanism 3. My real code is more involved so 1) is not ideal.